# Run a function after CSS link's media attribute is changed

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to dynamically change the media attribute of a CSS link tag and I need to run a function *after* the new CSS is applied.

I have a CSS stylesheet link tag

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

Inside my JavaScript code, I want to change the `media` attribute from `print` to `all`, and after the new style changes are applied to my page, I need to run a function.

Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
if (myCSSlink.getAttribute("media") === "print") {
                myCSSlink.setAttribute("media", "all");
                myCSSlink.onload = () => {
                    //do some work
                };

}
```

At this point, I'm assuming that after the `media` attribute is changed, the CSS loads again.
But my code inside the anonymous arrow function doesn't seem to work. How can I approach this?

Comment: Are you sure that changing a media query would trigger a reload? Have you tried running the function straight after changing the media query, ie without assuming a reload would take place?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an onload handler to do both - change the media attribute and run your custom onload function.

```js
function onLoad(link) {
    link.setAttribute('media', 'all');
    yourCustomFunction();
}
```

```html
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="onLoad(this);">
```